# Dart check DateTime for the last day

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a List of different DateTime where for each month of the year there are from 7-15 days with an interval of a couple of days. For example: 01.07, 04.07, 09.07, 14.07, 20.07..., 04.08, 10.08
Question: How do I check if the date is the last for the given month?
For example, the date 23.07 may be the last date for the month number 07.
Thanks!

Comment: your list type is DateTime?

Comment: could you include your list?

Comment: Yes, my list is date time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter check last day in the month (List of datetime)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74006620/flutter-check-last-day-in-the-month-list-of-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume this is your list:

```
List<DateTime> dates = [
    DateTime(2022, 07, 01),
    DateTime(2022, 07, 04),
    DateTime(2022, 07, 05),
    DateTime(2022, 07, 09),
    DateTime(2022, 07, 14),
    DateTime(2022, 07, 20),
    DateTime(2022, 07, 24),
    DateTime(2022, 08, 04),
  ];
```

with [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package you can grouped your dates by its month, like:

```
var grouped = groupBy(
    dates,
    (DateTime date) => date.month,
);
print("grouped = $grouped");// grouped = {7: [2022-07-01 00:00:00.000, 2022-07-04 00:00:00.000, 2022-07-05 00:00:00.000, 2022-07-09 00:00:00.000, 2022-07-14 00:00:00.000, 2022-07-20 00:00:00.000, 2022-07-24 00:00:00.000], 8: [2022-08-04 00:00:00.000]}
```

full example of what you want:

```
class TestingDesign2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestingDesign2({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestingDesign2> createState() => _TestingDesign2State();
}

class _TestingDesign2State extends State<TestingDesign2> {
  List<DateTime> dates = [
    DateTime(2022, 07, 01),
    DateTime(2022, 07, 04),
    DateTime(2022, 07, 05),
    DateTime(2022, 07, 09),
    DateTime(2022, 07, 14),
    DateTime(2022, 07, 20),
    DateTime(2022, 07, 24),
    DateTime(2022, 08, 04),
  ];
  List months = [
    'jan',
    'feb',
    'mar',
    'april',
    'may',
    'jun',
    'july',
    'aug',
    'sep',
    'oct',
    'nov',
    'dec'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var grouped = groupBy(
      dates,
      (DateTime date) => date.month,
    );
    List<Widget> items = grouped.entries
        .map((e) => Row(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: e.value
                      .map((date) => Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(date.day.toString()),
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
                Text(months[e.key])
              ],
            ))
        .toList();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              children: items,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But isn't there some function that checks for incoming dates? Through conditional statements, for example.

Comment: if you provide me a simple situation I could help you better, for example tell where do you want this?

Comment: like this https://wampi.ru/image/RW01PT7

Comment: I recommended this approach to achieve what you wnat.

Comment: Aw, bro, you're great! May all be well in your life. :D